# Gratis personal finance manager with virtual account

Tags: gratis, finance

Looking for a personal finance tool with the following must-haves:

- Auto integration for cash accounts and investments.
- Auto categorization of cash activity.
- Virtual accounts/envelopes - as in the ability to sequester money in a single real account into several virtual accounts.
- Free as in beer (for any number of accounts).
- Reputable.

May be Windows desktop, web, or Android app based, and I don't mind ads.

I have checked responses to [Gratis personal finance manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/gratis-personal-finance-manager) and [Desktop software to manage my finances with virtual accounts](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37992/desktop-software-to-manage-my-finances-with-virtual-accounts), but these aren't good matches.

Essentially, the ideal tool would be a [Personal Capital](https://www.personalcapital.com/) with virtual accounts.

Have already looked into many solutions, but they are not fits for the following primary reasons ...

- Not free ([Mvelopes](https://www.mvelopes.com/), [Goodbudget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dayspringtech.envelopes), [YNAB](https://www.youneedabudget.com/))
- Not automatic ([GnuCash](https://gnucash.org/), [SimpleBudget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplebudget&hl=en))
- No virtual accounts/envelopes ([Mint](https://www.mint.com/), [Personal Capital](https://www.personalcapital.com/))

Comment: Personal sensitive data IMHO don't go well with ads/trackers, and I'd especially not put them on a mobile device – but no morales here: for Android, be welcome to check with [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_budget). Can't give a straight recommendation as for reasons mentioned I'm not using any ;) Good luck, and feel free to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) if you find something!

Comment: By “automatic,” do you mean that you require the software to automatically download transactions from your bank?

Comment: @BenMiller yeah, for instance, it automatically queries accounts on a schedule or when the user logs in to it.

Comment: @M.Thompson That’s a feature not typically found in gratis products, as it is an ongoing service and requires some work to maintain compatibility with ever-changing bank systems.

Comment: Sure, I certainly understand that developers need compensation, which is why I accept alternative modes of revenue generation, like ads (as Mint does) or other services (like investment advice for Personal Capital).